# Gridview with linq and transactions

Tags: linq-to-sql, gridview

is it posible to implement a gridview with linq 2 SQL entities that allow commit all the updated rows together after a button click or maybe a way to rollback the changes if the user clicks a cancel button?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for *in-memory transactionality* (meaning that you could roll back the changes without doing a retrieval), then no, this isn't possible using LINQ 2 SQL entities, as they don't implement the `IEditableObject` interface.